# database normalization, second normal form exercise

Tags: database, database-normalization

I am trying to solve an exercise related with functional dependencies and database normalization. I have solved many exercises similar to this one but I can not solved this.

For a given a Schema with a single relation R(A, B, C, D, E, F), the set of all functional dependencies that holds is:

```
BC -> DC
B -> E
D -> EF
FC -> E
C -> A
F -> E
```

Normalize the relation R so it satisfies the 2NF AND  all Functional dependencies are kept.

What I have done so far:

1) Find candidate keys: {BC} (I think there is a single candidate key)

2) Find a minimal equivalent set of dependencies

```
BC → D
B → E
D → EF
C → A
F → E
```

3) use C → A (A depends  on C that is part of the candidate key, A is non prime)

```
R1(B, C, D, E, F), candidate keys BC
R2(C, A) candidate keys C
```

4) use B → E (E depends  on B that is part of the candidate key, E is non prime)

```
R2(C, A) candidate keys C
R11(B, C, D, F) candidate keys BC
R12(B, E) candidate keys B
```

I do not like this normalization because the functional dependency  F -> E can not be recovered. I am looking for a decomposition of R such that the second normal form is satisfied and no functional dependency is lost. Can anybody help me to find such decomposition?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying edits. So your actual question is, what is an algorithm to decompose to 2NF that does not lose FDs ("preserves FDs" is the technical term) & how is it used with your FDs. You don't need to give a random decompostion to ask that--it's irrelevant. Also you shouldn't ask the 2nd half until you get an answer to the 1st half & show your work using the algorithm until you are stuck. I already answered the part about the algorithm--try all decompositions or use a standard 3NF algorithm. Look in your textbook. PS The algorithm uses a FD cover or closure--not just "a set".

Comment: But that is *not* all the FDs that hold. When some hold, all the FDs that Armstrong's axioms give from them hold. I already told you, it is usually a *cover* that is given. Find out what one is. Look at how a cover is mentioned in examples like this in your textbook. And what was the result of your search for a 3NF normalization algorithm? PS You should also understand when checking NFs that the definitions refer to *all* the FDs that hold, not just those in a cover that was given. If your decomposition had preserved all the FDs in that list, it still might not have preserved all the FDs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Functional dependencies after normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48373595/3404097) (Updated with algorithm.)