# How do i normalize the given entities in the database ER diagram. And also shouldn't normalization be done before making the ER diagram?

Tags: database, entity-relationship, database-normalization, 3nf, first-normal-form

This is the given ER diagram.
This requires me to convert the ER diagram to Tables/Entities, and then Normalize them to at least 3NF, now almost all the entities except the `Food Items` entity is in 1NF. If I remove the columns `vitamins` and `minerals` from the `Food Items` table and make separate tables called `Food Item Vitamin` with attributes (`id`(primary key), `fooditem_id`(foreign key), `vitamin`) and `Food Item Mineral` with attributes (`id`(primary key), `fooditem_id`(foreign key), `mineral`), these tables would also become into the 1NF form. Now how do I proceed in converting them into 2Nf and then 3NF, for this entity and the rest.
[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL--text. (You could also give a diagram, but it's likely redundant.) Put all but only what is needed to ask into your post. Give credit when quoting.

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question?What published DB design textbook/reference are you following? What method? What are its steps? Where is the 1st place you are stuck? Why/how? You essentially ask us to (re)write a textbook for an unidentified method & bespoke tutorial with no details on what you misunderstand or do or don't understand. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs. [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [“help me"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097)

Comment: "into 2Nf and then 3NF" 2NF is not useful & normalization to 3NF is not done by going through 2NF--that can stop good 3NF designs from arising. So you don't seem to understand what you are supposed to do. What was your exact assignment? PS [Bernstein's FD-preserving 3NF "synthesis" algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48374962/3404097)